# How can I configure Sql Server Management Studio to ignore certain extended properties on a view when creating a BACPAC?

Tags: sql-server, bacpac

When I try to generate a BACPAC from a database running on a local MSSQL database I get an error:

```
One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71564: The element Extended Property: [dbo].[EnabledCompany].[MS_DiagramPane1] is not   supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file).
Error SQL71564: The element Extended Property: [dbo].[EnabledCompany].[MS_DiagramPaneCount] is not supported when used as part of a data package (.bacpac file).
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
```

[EnabledCompany] is a simple view made up of a select from a single table with a single where filter based on a bit column. (It only shows companies where IsEnabled == true).

I'm using SQL Server 2014 with the latest version of the tooling (SSMS).

Comment: Extended property support is available in the latest SQL Database Update V12 (preview) - see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/ for details. If you use the SSMS CU5 update (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3011055) this has support for exporting bacpac files containing extended properties, which can then be imported into a DB that has V12 preview support enabled

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this is to delete the extended properties on the view.

This will then allow the database to be exported.

However, it will break the graphical designer for the view in question and so isn't ideal.